# Broadcom WICED API will not disconnect Bluetooth LE connection

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, broadcom

I've developed embedded software on a central board and a peripheral board, using Broadcom's WICED v1.0.1 API.

When my central scans, it detects the peripheral advertisement.
When my central then connects, that works, and the peripheral detects this.
My central can then send a write request, which the peripheral detects and responds to by sending back a notification, which the central receives ok.

BUT, when the central then disconnects, so it can poll next peripheral, nothing happens; the peripheral does not fire its link down (disconnection) callback.

To disconnect, my central executes this Broadcom API function:
        blecm_CreateConnectionCancel();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blecm_disconnect(BT_ERROR_CODE_CONNECTION_TERMINATED_BY_LOCAL_HOST);

Comment: I dug around WICED and discovered this function, which works.